# Solving for Variable in Rational Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I have a really simple issue, I am doing a circuit problem and I get a final equation:

$$\frac{v_1-12}{2\ k\Omega}+\frac{v_1}{k\Omega}+\frac{v_1}{r_1}=0$$

Im trying to get $v_1$ by itself, the solution is $$v_1=\frac{12r_1}{3r_1+2}.$$

I've tried separating the variables, and I know this is embarrassingly simplistic, but can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore the $k\Omega$ units and ignore the indices (we don't have any $v_2$ or $r_2$ anyways). You equation now reads

$$\begin{array}{rl|l}
\frac{v-12}2 + v + \frac vr & = 0 & - \frac{12}2 \\
\frac v2 + v + \frac vr & = \frac{12}2 = 6 & \text{factor } v \\
v(\frac12 + 1 + \frac1r) & = 6 &  \div (\frac32 + \frac1r) \\
v & = \frac6{\frac1r + \frac32} &  \text{expand with } r \\
& = \frac{6r}{1+\frac32 r} &  \text{expand with } 2 \\
& = \frac{12r}{2+3r}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps 
$$ \frac{v_1-12}{2k\Omega} + \frac{v_1}{k\Omega}+ \frac{v_1}{r_1} =0 $$
$$ \frac{v_1}{2k\Omega}- \frac{12}{2k\Omega} + \frac{v_1}{k\Omega}+ \frac{v_1}{r_1} =0 $$
$$ \frac{v_1}{2k\Omega}+ \frac{v_1}{k\Omega}+ \frac{v_1}{r_1} = \frac{12}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1\left(\frac{1}{2k\Omega}+ \frac{1}{k\Omega}+ \frac{1}{r_1}\right)= \frac{12}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1\left(\frac{k\Omega +2k\Omega}{2k\Omega^2}+ \frac{1}{r_1}\right)= \frac{12}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1\left(\frac{3k\Omega}{2k\Omega^2}+ \frac{1}{r_1}\right)= \frac{12}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1\left(\frac{3k\Omega r_1+ 2k\Omega^2 }{2k\Omega^2 r_1}\right)= \frac{12}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1\left(3k\Omega r_1+ 2k\Omega^2 \right)= \frac{12(2k\Omega^2 r_1)}{2k\Omega} $$
$$ v_1= \frac{12(2k\Omega^2 r_1)}{2k\Omega(3k\Omega r_1+ 2k\Omega^2)} $$
$$ v_1= \frac{12k\Omega r_1}{3k\Omega r_1+ 2k\Omega^2} = \frac{12 r_1}{3 r_1+ 2k\Omega} $$